# How do I remove spaces from all the file-names in the current directory

Tags: language-agnostic, whitespace, filenames

As the title suggests how do I remove spaces from all the files in the current directory ?

Example

`file name.mp3` should become `filename.mp3`

Note:

- I am open to an answer in any language.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you will have two original files that reduce to the same file name? E.g. `file name a.mp3` and `filename a.mp3`.

Comment: I am not worried about conflicts, That is probably for another question.

Comment: How about a JVM Lang solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with sh

```
for file in *' '*; do [ -f "$file" ] && mv "$file" "`echo $file|tr -d '[:space:]'`"; done
```

with perl 5.14 (replace `y/ //dr` by `do{($x=$_)=~y/ //d;$x}` for older versions)

```
# Linux/Unix
perl -e 'rename$_,y/ //drfor<"* *">'
# Windows
perl -e "rename$_,y/ //drfor<'* *'>"
```

with Java

```
import java.io.File;

public class M {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String o,n;
        for (File old : new File(".").listFiles()) {
            o=old.getName();
            if (!o.contains(" ")) continue;
            n=o.replaceAll(" ", "");
            old.renameTo(new File(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use bash here-strings to make it a bit neater: `mv "$file" $(tr -d '[:space:]' <<< $file)` -- since we're removing whitespace, we don't have to worry about quoting the new file name.

Comment: I know but it doesn't work with sh, following a comment the OP is using sh

Comment: Ah, he removed bash from the question tags.

Comment: @glennjackman : Well the question was more interesting if it were language-agnostic .

Answer (score 18):

I am a big fan of python, so here is a python script for doing the same

```
import os
for f in os.listdir("."):
    r = f.replace(" ","")
    if( r != f):
        os.rename(f,r)
```

Comment: Surely [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename) would be preferable than calling out to `mv`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in * ; do 
  if [ "$i" != ${i//[[:space:]]} ] ; 
  then
    mv "$i" "${i//[[:space:]]}"
  fi
done
```

`${i//[[:space:]]}` removes all the spaces in a string.

Comment: You need to quote `$i` in case it does, in fact, contain spaces.

Comment: Then why is your question tagged `bash`? They are two different shells.

Comment: Ya but most people use bash, and this is relevant in both bash and zsh

Comment: Except your answer does not work in `bash`. The distinction is quite relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're language agnostic, here's a ruby one-liner:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.foreach(".") {|f| f.count(" \t") > 0 and File.rename(f, f.delete(" \t"))}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 | awk '/ /{a=$0;gsub(/ /,"");b="mv \""a"\" "$0;system(b);}'
```

Comment: `ls -1 | awk '/ /{a=$0;gsub(/ /,"");b="mv \""a"\" "$0;system(b);}'
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Throws the above errors

Comment: what is the version of awk u r using.if solaris then u can use nawk

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 with mawk 1.3.3

Answer (score 1):

This renames an old file only if the old file name contained a space
and the new file doesn't already exist.

```
for old in *; do
    new="${old//[[:space:]]}"
    [[ $old = $new || -f $new ]] || mv "$old" "$new"
done
```